# Adding Header and Footer content to existing .xlsx file

Tags: python, xlsx, xlsxwriter

I have some existing `.xlsx` files. I want to add content to the header and footer to each file in every worksheet without changing the content within the file. I have the following code with the xlsxwriter module:

```
import xlsxwriter

workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('headers_footers.xlsx')
preview = 'Select Print Preview to see the header and footer'

worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet('Test')
header = '&L&G'
footer = '&L Content Footer'

worksheet.set_header(header, {'image_left': 'logo_white.jpg'})
worksheet.set_footer(footer)

workbook.close()
```

Works fine when creating a new `.xlsx` file but it does not adding the header- and footercontent to existing files.
Where is the problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

For everyone who want to do the same: I contacted the Developerl. There is no possibility to change existing `.xlsx` files with `xlsxwriter`. The Dev recommend `openpyxl` instead.